# How to send request include query string with yahoo mail address to aspx page

Tags: asp.net, yahoo-mail

I want send an email through  query string to a Aspx page.

When it included Yahoo e-mail servers, the page  transmitted to the main Yahoo page But if email is  from other servers , it is no problem. This newly created problem.

ex : `google.com/page.aspx?emailIs=myEmail@yahoo.com`

its redirected to yahoo website but the bellow ex work correctly
ex : `google.com/page.aspx?emailIs=myEmail@gmail.com`

Comment: *if email is from other servers , it is no problem. This newly created problem.* can you explain this?

Comment: you can test that request : google.com/page.aspx?emailIs=myEmail@yahoo.com . and test that google.com/page.aspx?emailIs=myEmail@outlook.com . you can compare these items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem happened in short time in DNS resolver in IRAN area.
when an URL included "yahoo.com" in parameters section, DNS resolver mistakenly get this and redirect to that.
this is resolved after a while